# How to build our own user define

Tags: google-maps

Can we create a user define custom base google map on which we can add our predefine landmark points?

Now in application we access google map with original information. Our GPS device returns location of current point with some description such as your vehicle is .. distance away from some xxx location.

So can we build to some user define google map on which we can add custom landmarks on google map, then we access that custom url to access google map.

Comment: Assuming that I have missed some detail.  If you would like to clarify we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a customized google map page, with your own landmark points.  You need to check out the [Google Maps API Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html).

To create markers ('*predefined landmark points*') on the map you need to instantiate [GMarker](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMarker) objects in Javascript using your latitude, longitude data.

Not quite clear on the last part of your question, but if you asking about linking to Google Maps at a particular latitude longitude, you can build a URL to do that:

```
http://maps.google.com.au/?ll=<latitude>,<longitude>&spn=<degrees high>,<degrees wide>
```

For example:

http://maps.google.com.au/?ll=-15.623037,18.388672&spn=65.61535,79.013672